# What is the appropriate tool to push at a center and pull on both sides to disassemble a seized object?

Tags: tools, rust

The part pictured below is a car part, but I'll likely get many more ideas on this site rather than on mechanics.SE.

Since they pour (literally) hundreds of thousands of tons of salt on the roads in my area, it's no surprise that a car will have salt dust a few days after washing. This deposit rusts and, in this case, seizes the rear window hinge.

[image: rear wiper hinge]

What is the correct tool to push at the centre screw (here the nut is removed) and to pull on both side of the wiper arm? This is attached to a rear window, and so any kind of hammering with a rubber mallet is not an option.

Attempts to spray over multiple days with a water displacement oil and to wiggle by hand have so far failed.

Comment: try the "Two Jaw Pilot Bearing Gear Puller, Carbon Steel Adjustable Bearing Puller for Slide Gears, Pulley, and Flywhee"

Comment: You probably want penetrating oil/spray instead of water displacement.  Ball joint separating tool might work if no space for pulling jaws,  but there should be a tool for window handles, instead of using a tool that might fit/work.  Auto transmission oil and acetone 50/50 mix is a homemade one that works as good as store brought ones.

Comment: Use lubricant as suggested by crip659, or W40, and let the lubricant sit overnight. Heat the outer surface with a heat gun, and try to wriggle it out.

Comment: it's  not a home improvement question ... ask at https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Might have some luck with a tie rod puller.

Answer (score 3):

Wiper arm attachment is rather small to be using any typical automotive puller. You could try a faucet handle puller (plumbing dept. in any decent hardware store) after soaking in some sort of "liquid wrench".